# How to effeciently apply function to all subarrays of a fixed size to an array in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Numpy, and recently I got stuck. I am writing a fractal compression algorithm, and one of its steps is to find closest subimage from a given image `resized_image` for a small given image(10x10 pixels,for example) `img` in terms of mean squared error after applying some transformations.
Now my function is looking like this:

```
def find_block_transform(image, resized_image, x, y, block_size, stride):
    best_transform=BlockTransform(0,0,0,0,0)
    bestMSE=1000000000
    img =image[y:y+block_size,x:x+block_size]
    print(resized_image.shape[0])
    for i in range(0,resized_image.shape[0]-block_size,stride):
        for j in range(0,resized_image.shape[1]-block_size,stride):
            domain=resized_image[i:i+block_size,j:j+block_size]
            DD=np.sum(domain*domain)
            DR=np.sum(domain*img)
            R=np.sum(img)
            D=np.sum(domain)
            q=(DR-D*R/(block_size*block_size))/(DD-D*D/(block_size*block_size))
            p=(R-D*q)/(block_size*block_size)
            MSE=mse(domain*q+p,img)
            if(MSE<bestMSE):
                bestMSE=MSE
                best_transform=BlockTransform(i,j,q,p,0)
    return best_transform
```

Unfortunately, this approach is very slow. For `resized_image` sized 256x256 and `block_size` sized 10x10 it takes almost 5 seconds. With `block_size` 50x50 it takes only a few fractions of second more.
I suppose that the code is so slow  because of double for loop. Is there a way to make it faster with Numpy?

Comment: To check: you want to run a function on independent (i.e., separate) 2D (square) subsets of a 2D array?

Comment: I see `img =image[y:y+block_size,x:x+block_size]`, which seems to be the subset. But I also see a double loop over the indices of the resized_image, with a certain step size (stride). It's that doulbe loop you'd like to avoid, but `img` doesn't really seem to directly involved in that (that is, it doesn't define the loops).

Comment: My goal is to find the best-suiting sub-image `domain` of `resized_image`  (which is, of course, 2D array of floats)  for given sub-image `img` of `image`, after applying some linear transformations to `domain`. So yes, I want to run a function on independent subsets of `resized_image` to find the best suiting one.

Comment: I don't know whether this can clarify my goal, but this is the algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_compression#Encoding